# Cannot set up a conda environment with python 3.10

Tags: conda, anaconda3

I am trying to set up a conda environment with python 3.10 installed. For some reason, no install commands for additional packages are working. For example, if I run `conda install pandas`, I get the error:

```sh
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.1
```

`conda install -c conda-forge pandas` doesn't work either. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thats a bug in conda, you can read more about it here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10969

Right now there is a PR to fix it but its not a released version. For now, just stick with

```
conda install python=3.9
```

Answer (score 17):

Adding an answer as this issue has been fixed in the latest conda update. I faced the same issue in conda version 4.10.1 but it worked fine in version 4.11.0.

Update conda to the latest version with

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Now install the required packages.

Comment: Solved my problem too.

Answer (score 15):

`conda install -n py310 python=3.10` works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I use MacOS Monterey. Preceded your suggestion with **conda update -all** and then attempted to run your command line. Got the error **EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: /Users/sesh/miniconda3/envs/py310**

Answer (score 9):

## Conda 4.10 is incompatible with python 3.10.

To use python 3.10 or newer, you need to update to conda 4.11+. If you cannot update conda, you need to revert to python 3.9 or older.

[Read more on the](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/10969) on the link provided by [vbraun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69492985/1837006). This reply is to clarify possibilities for the users.

Comment: If there's anything I could do to improve this answer, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Can also use the `conda-forge` channel:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge python=3.10
```

Answer (score 1):

We must create a new environment with latest version of python and change to this new environment inside anaconda navigator