# When install torch in conda environment. ResolvePackageNotFound: - python=3.1

Tags: python, anaconda, torch

When I want to install torch in my conda virtual environment using

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch`,

it shows the error:`ResolvePackageNotFound:    - python=3.1`
I know that it is a bug in conda by referring [Cannot set up a conda environment with python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481608/cannot-set-up-a-conda-environment-with-python-3-10). I should change conda environment python version to python3.9 to solve problem using

`conda install python=3.9`

But same error still shows why I install torch.
Please help

Comment: What do you expect the `-c` to do at this place?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new environemnt to be sure that the new python version is installed. I am not sure, but if you only installed it like this I think it skips the installation since `python 3.10` is still installed. try: `conda create -n py39 python=3.9` to create a py39 environment.

Comment: @ Klaus D, It is a command to install pytorch. Copying from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/. Actually I don't know what ```-c``` will do.

Comment: The top/accepted answer from the cited question is no longer appropriate. Instead, update your Conda (`conda update -n base conda`). Unless there is some other error, this is a duplicate.