# Creating a conda virtual environment with a specific python version (e.g., python 3.10) and verifying it

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've created a virtual environment with a specific python version (e.g., python 3.10) using conda but when I try to verify that the environment is using the python version I created it shows me the version I was using before I created the virtual environment.

In Jupyter lab I've create the virtual environment and activate it with this.

```
conda create --name snakes python=3.10 
conda activate snakes
```

Then I try to verify it.

```
python --version
```

I get python 2.7.18

Comment: What does this say: `which python`? Is the path as expected, based on your conda env?

Comment: What does this say: `alias python`? Do you have an alias that points to some other version of python?

Comment: which python : /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: alias python: no result

Comment: You have not activated your conda environment properly or have not set up conda or conda environment properly. The python path that you showed is definitely not from the conda environment. It should look similar to this: `/Users/your_user_name/miniconda3/envs/snakes/bin/python`

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69481608/967621 , specifically, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70924501/967621

Comment: I tried the 'conda install -c conda-forge python=3.10', and it still didn't work.

Comment: I'm going to try to set it up again.

Comment: Possibly your `conda activate` is broken. Could try to clean up your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc` and rerun `conda init`. This can also completely depend on the *terminal* you use, e.g., VSCode and `tmux` users often have issues.